Is it possible to implement these array flattening/unflattening functions in current Rust?
It comes close to working, but fails on an internal-looking error. My general idea was to structure the array size as INNER * OUTER to prove to the compiler that it factors cleanly.
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]
#![allow(incomplete_features)]


use core::mem;

pub fn flatten_array<T, const OUTER: usize, const INNER: usize>(
  x: &[[T; INNER]; OUTER],
) -> &[T; INNER * OUTER] {
  unsafe { mem::transmute(x) }
}

pub fn unflatten_array<T, const OUTER: usize, const INNER: usize>(
  x: &[T; INNER * OUTER],
) -> &[[T; INNER]; OUTER] {
  unsafe { mem::transmute(x) }
}

pub fn unflatten_bytes_4<const N: usize>(
  x: [u8; 4 * (N / 4)],
) -> [[u8; 4]; N / 4] {
  *unflatten_array(&x)
}

// pub fn should_fail() { unflatten_bytes_4::<7>([0; 7]); }
pub fn should_work() { unflatten_bytes_4::<8>([0; 8]); }

The error being
error: failed to get layout for [[u8; 4]; 8 / 4]: the type `[[u8; 4]; 8 / 4]` has an unknown layout

Playground

Note that this version works, but is less convenient because the generic N param at the usage site isn't the full array size (and can't be inferred)
pub fn unflatten_bytes_4<const N: usize>(
  x: [u8; 4 * N],
) -> [[u8; 4]; N] {
  *unflatten_array(&x)
}

pub fn should_work() { unflatten_bytes_4::<2>([0; 8]); }

Playground

Seems like you bug you should report to me.
